# Establish a connection between the raspberry and mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, raspberry-pi, connection

I created a database on my pc and I wanted to create a javascript script using node, which would allow me to access all the database data installed on my pc. I tried to establish a connection between raspberry and my pc locally using the same router. Unfortunately, it always gives me connection errors.
Looking a bit on the internet I found many posts about "bindIp" of mongodb, but despite several tests found the same problem.

## network interfaces

net:
   port: 27017
   #bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.8
sorry for my English.

Code raspberry:

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://168.192.1.6:27017/"; //ip my pc and mongodb

var day = new Date();

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("qadrio");
  dbo.collection("pin").findOne({}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("NAME DEVICE: "+ result.name);
    console.log("ERROR: "+ err);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

I'm not an expert so I ask for help from you users. I would like to understand how it is done. I think the problem is mongodb itself that blocks external connections except the local ones of the pc.

Error Message

> failed to connect to server [168.192.1.6:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to 168.192.1.6:27017 timed out] at Pool. at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13) at Connection. at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13) at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13) at Socket. at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13) at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13) at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:449:8) at ontimeout (timers.js:425:11)

Comment: Hii @Salvatore welcome to so, can you post the error messge?

Comment: @JanithKasun failed to connect to server [168.192.1.6:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to 168.192.1.6:27017 timed out]
    at Pool.<anonymous>
    at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Connection.
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:449:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:425:11)

Comment: `168.192.1.6:27017` is this a vaild LAN addess isn't it `192.168.1.6:27017`

Comment: @JanithKasun Ok, how can I solve?

Comment: @JanithKasun with new address (node:4345) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
      throw err;
      ^

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [192.168.1.6:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to 192.168.1.6:27017 timed out]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)

Comment: Please see the below answer

Comment: @JanithKasun the problem continues to persist

Comment: Did u resolved the issue, I am getting the same error